# Limiting the input in the Console

Tags: c#, input, console, console-application, readline

I'm making a maze game. how can i limit the number of characters the user will input after Console.Read()?
i need to limit it so that if the user inputs a very long string, it will overwrite my Maze. 
If you're planning to tell me to just rewrite the maze afterwards, i'll say no. I can't. It will require me another long process, believe me. I just want a simple code for limiting the input.

Here's a screenshot demonstrating the problem. You see that `asdasjhasd....` in the screen? See how it messes up the maze? I want to limit the numbers of characters the User can input so that it will not reach the maze. Can you guys tell me what code to use?

[image]

SOLVED

```
string str = string.Empty;
while (true)
{
    char c = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;
    if (c == '\r')
        break;
    if (c == '\b' )
    {
        if (str != "")
        {
            str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
            Console.Write("\b \b");
        }
    }
    else if (str.Length < limit)
    {
        Console.Write(c);
        str += c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code how you are reading from the console.

Answer (score 5):

A workaround is to use `Console.ReadKey` instead:

```
string str = string.Empty;
do
{
    char c = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
    if(c == '\n')
        break;

    str += c;
}while(str.Length < 7);
```

Comment: Does `\n` work? Doesn't the return key correspond to `\r` in this context? And you should at least support for backspace. And auto-accepting the input one the max length is reached is usually a bad idea, it should stop accepting input but still allow corrections of the previous input.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I'm not sure about `\n` or `\r` - and can't test it right now. For the auto-accepting and backspace, you're right that this is a *very* simple input handler, that lacks lots of features.

Comment: @Anders hmm i think you guys doesn't get the question. I'll post another question with images so i can explain clearly.

Comment: @Reinan this answer prevents the behavior shown in your image.

Comment: Then you could explain what you're doing and what you mean by not working. You still haven't posted the the code in which you attempt to use this. This looks correct once you replace `\n` by `\r` and `string.empty` by `string.Empty`

Comment: If you don't post enough information about your problem we can't help you.

Comment: @Reinan Contawi, you don't want to be helped. How do you expect people being able to help you if you don't show your source code? It's very easy to say *not working*. What is not working, what have you tried so far, how does your code look like? Please provide more information and you will get help.

Comment: I adjusted 7 to 15. after i press enter while my string is not yet the length of 15, my programs get funny. it seems like the next codes are not working anymore.

Comment: @Reinan that's why I said that you should replace `\n` by `\r`

Comment: It's working now. Thanks @CodeInChaos Sorry for being stupid earlier. That Matthew really pissed me off. I'm so sorry. >.<

Comment: My only problem now is the backspace. Please help me if you want. (But i think i can already solve this myself. better yet, help me)

Comment: Closing your duplicate question was the right thing to do. No reason to complain about Matthew.

Answer (score 3):

Just tested a slightly modified version of Anders's answer, and it works:

```
public static string ReadLimited(int limit)
{
    string str = string.Empty;
    while (str.Length < limit)
    {
        char c = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        if (c == '\r')
            break;
        str += c;
    } 
    return str;
}
```

It doesn't handle backspace and autoaccepts any string that reaches the limit, but apart from these issues it works.

And a better version that fixed these problems:

```
public static string ReadLimited(int limit)
{
    string str = string.Empty;
    while (true)
    {
        char c = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;
        if (c == '\r')
            break;
        if (c == '\b' )
        {
            if (str != "")
            {
                str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
                Console.Write("\b \b");
            }
        }
        else if (str.Length < limit)
        {
            Console.Write(c);
            str += c;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: I tried to revise this code a little. It still backspaces even the string is already empty. I changed CW to CW(" \b"); and else if (str...) to just else str += c;

Comment: it still backspaces even the string is empty.

Comment: btw. what does While (true) means? and does str.Substring(0, str.Length-1) deletes the last char in my string?

Comment: `while(true)` is an endless loop, I'm using `break` to exit the loop. Bad style, but I'm too lazy to improve it. `str.Substring(0, str.Length-1)` returns a new string without the last character.

Comment: This is definitely an improvement over my version, +1.

Comment: @Reinan Contawi - If it worked for you you should consider marking this answer as accepted (click the tick mark to the left of the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Console.ReadKey(true);` - it will return a `ConsoleKey` that you can add to your input Stream.
If you want to convert it to a `char`, simply use the property `.KeyChar`.
Because `intercept` is set to true - it will not display the character in the console window at all.

Comment: i used cheat = Console.ReadKey(true); It's not working. What's wrong? do i need to declare a bool named true?